# Dependencies betwee fields in Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with two fields, which are based on two models. What I need? If you select a specific category, you can select only the sub-categories, which binds to a specific category.

Forms

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label='Category',
    queryset=Category.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select,
    required=False)

subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label='Subcategory',
    queryset=SubCategory.objects.all(), #may be something like SubCategory.objects.filter(??????)
    widget=forms.Select,
    required=False)
```

Comment: I am assuming that you want the behavior present client side? You will need to use AJAX if so. Not to mention, you will have to write validation of the form submission to avoid DQ issues. May I suggest that you use the package [Django MPTT](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt)? This package does the whole category/subcategory/hierarchal structures quite splendidly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax/jQuery solution:

1. use jQuery (include jQuery file to your template, for example call it from CDN) at the end of your template to make ajax get request after category is selected

   - when template will load the subcategory field will be cleared and Select category option will be prepended to it
   - when category will be selected change function will trigger ajax GET request on request_url
   - the selected category (category_id) will be passed to url and than to view (see point 3. to get the idea what happend after view runs)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
  $('select[name=subcategory]').empty();
  $('select[name=subcategory]').prepend('<option value="Not selected" selected disabled>Select Category...</option>');
  // called when category field changes from initial value
  $('select[name=massage]').change(function(){
    if($("#id_category option:selected").text()) != (YOU SHOULD INSERT THE INITIAL VALUE OF THE CATEGORY FIELD WHEN IT IS NOT SELECTED) {
    category_id = $('select[name=category]').val();
    request_url = '/get_subcategory/' + category_id + '/';
      $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
          $.each(data, function(key, value){
            $('select[name=subcategory]').empty();
            $('select[name=subcategory]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
          });
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

2. create appropriate url in urls.py that will handle the get request from ajax in jQuery, when category is selected:

in urls.py file:

```
url(r'^get_subcategory/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_subcategory, name='get_subcategory'),
```

3. now create the appropriate view in views.py that will run after get request at previous url:

   - subcategories that are linked to selected category (identified by category_id) will be filtered and sent back to template
   - in ajax success function (see point 1.) the subcategory dropdown menu will be populated with filtered subcategories

in views.py file:

```
import json

def get_subcategory(request, category_id):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
    subcategories = category.subcategory_set.all()
    subcategories_dict = {}
    for subcategory in subcategories:
    // if your subcategory has field name
    subcategories_dict[subcategory.id] = subcategory.name
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(subcategories_dict), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but unfortunately I have the error in ajax response. What could be the problem? `jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/callboard/get_subcategory/2/`

Comment: I found the error. In general your code works as I wanted.

Comment: I see you solved the problem before I  could respond. That's great. It would be cool if you could write down what was the cause of error so I could update the code for others.

Comment: There is one typo in your code(`$('select[name=massage]')` you should write `subcategory` instead `massage`) but it wasn't a reason of my issue. I made error in my urls file.